# "Can't implicitly convert from type "Blah" to type 'string'

Tags: c#, struct, xamarin

I'm using a struct in c# to return two variables from a function. I declared the new struct "Solutions" and I'm now trying to set up all of my allocations. However, when setting one of my possible results to a member of the struct, it says that I can't implicitly convert the types, however they should both be strings by the definition of the member of the struct.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
}
    Solution quadratic (int a, int b, int c)
    {
        d = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow (b, 2)) - (4 * a * c);
        if (d < 0) {
            Solution fail;
            fail.solution1 = fail;
            fail.solution2 = fail;
            return(fail);
        } else{
            Solution solutions;
            solutions.solution1 = Convert.ToString((-1 * b + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt (d))) / (2 * a));
            solutions.solution2 = Convert.ToString((-1 * b - Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt (d))) / (2 * a));
            return(solutions);
        }
    }
    public struct Solution
    {
        public string solution1;
        public string solution2;
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE : I did a stupid. I named the new "Solution" struct "fail", which also happened to be the name of the string I was trying to assign to it. BE CAREFUL WITH YOUR VARIABLE NAMES, KIDS

Comment: What actually is "blah"?  "Solution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
fail.solution1 = fail; 
fail.solution2 = fail;
```

You are trying to assign variable fail (of type Solution) to variables fail.solution1 and fail.solution2 (of type string).

Answer (score 1):

The error is hiding here

```
        Solution fail;
        fail.solution1 = fail;
        fail.solution2 = fail;
```

You are trying to assing to `solution1` a `fail` which is struct, not string.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: `fail`is Solution type, and `fail.solution1`/ `fail.solution3` are string type. Try this:

```
Solution fail = new Solution();
fail.solition1 = string.empty(); // Or you value
fail.solition2 = string.empty(); // Or you value
return fail;
```

Why you return this: `return (fail)`? Why the brackets?